# Error: stack level too deep (SystemStackError)

Tags: ruby, recursion, integer, multiplication

I am getting this error:

```
integerMultiplication.rb:4:in `untMul': stack level too deep (SystemStackError)
```

in this code:

```
def untMul(x, y)
  xDigits = x.to_s.split(//).map{|chr| chr.to_i}
  yDigits = y.to_s.split(//).map{|chr| chr.to_i}
  n = xDigits.size
  a = xDigits[0, xDigits.size / 2]
  b = xDigits[xDigits.size / 2 ... xDigits.size]
  c = yDigits[0, yDigits.size / 2]
  d = yDigits[yDigits.size / 2 ... yDigits.size]
  ac = untMul(a,c)
  bd = untMul(b,d)
  adPlusBd = untMul(a + b, c + d) - ac - bd 
  return 10**n * ac + 10**n/2 * adPlusBd + bd
end

untMul(12, 54)
```

Could someone please help with understand what is going wrong here? I am trying to implement Karatsuba multiplication.

Comment: BTW if you had googled that error message you would have found streams of answers and questions leading you right to what is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Infinite recursion is going on.  untMul is calling itself repeatedly until the stack runs out of space.  You need to set a condition case to make it complete before that happens.